# phpmyadmin host not found !

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi im using xampp & I  am trying to connect using php.

```
<?php $server = localhost; $username = root; $password = ******;?>

$sql_connections = mysql_connect("$server, $username, $password") or die(mysql_error());

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Database Manager\admin\sql_functions.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. (trying to connect via tcp://localhost, root, usd27498:3306) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Database Manager\admin\sql_functions.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using incorrect notation to set the server:

```
 mysql_connect("$server, $username, $password")
```

needs to be

```
 mysql_connect($server, $username, $password)
```

[manual on mysql_connect](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect)

Answer (score 0):

did you start your xampp control panel?

is your apache running? try http://localhost

is your mysql running?

try http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

depending the error you are getting is what you have to do.
I am guessing that you might have a problem with the mysql password.

Comment: Yes apache & mysql are running & the password is correct for root in localhost. I tried http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ & it works fine.

Comment: you have a syntax error: mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) should be written instead.